# Why isn't my line showing up in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

http://codepen.io/djminkus/pen/Wxkamq

All I want to do is draw a colored line between a few points, but my code isn't working and I don't know why. I'm very new to three.js, so I figured someone more experienced with it could give me a quick pointer.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var line = (function(){
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
  });

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 )
  );

  var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
  // scene.add( line );
  return line;
})();
scene.add(line);

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x0f00ff
});

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
  new THREE.Vector3( -10, 5, 7 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 )
);

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add( line );

var render=function() {
  // cube.rotation.x += x_vel;
  // cube.rotation.y += y_vel;
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
var x_vel = .001; //rotation speed in x
var y_vel = .01; // rotation speed in y
render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have your camera pointed at the line....

change geometry to

```
geometry.vertices.push(
  new THREE.Vector3( -10, -5, -7 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 0, 10, 0 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 0 )
);
```

and you should see the line

Comment: you can add `camera.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,60));` to get your camera farther and see the whole line